# It says subquery returns more than 1 row but I'm not sure why?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've joined around 4 tables in my database and I am trying to get a shortlist of candidates who meet these requirements.
It won't display another person who meets these requirements. It for some reason works when there is one candidate that meets them.

```
SELECT job_seeker.seeker_fn
    ,job_seeker.seeker_ln
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT job_seeker.position_title) AS 'Required Skills'
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT quali_name) AS 'Required Qualifications'
FROM job_seeker
INNER JOIN job_seeker_profile ON job_seeker.seeker_ID = job_seeker_profile.seeker_ID
INNER JOIN qualifications ON job_seeker_profile.qualification_ID = qualifications.qualification_ID
INNER JOIN skill_types ON job_seeker_profile.skill_type_ID = skill_types.skill_type_ID
INNER JOIN skill_areas ON skill_areas.area_ID = skill_areas.area_ID
INNER JOIN job_pos ON qualifications.qualification_ID = job_pos.qualification_ID
WHERE (
        SELECT job_pos.qualification_ID
        FROM job_pos
        WHERE job_pos.qualification_ID = job_seeker_profile.skill_type_ID
            AND job_pos.qualification_ID = job_seeker_profile.qualification_ID
        )
    AND job_pos.job_position_ID = 7;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EuoA.png)

Answer (score 1):

In your query you have a WHERE condition that compare the result related  to AND operator for a value = 7

```
where ( subquery ) AND job_pos.job_position_ID  = 7
```

without going into the merits of the conceptual error that is at the basis of your syntax (correct in itself but which implies a different need)

this is wrong because the number of the row from the subquery and the number of the row managed by the AND clause are not the same

Looking to your query you don't need the subquery but just a where condition

the correct syntax should be

```
SELECT job_seeker.seeker_fn
    ,job_seeker.seeker_ln
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT job_seeker.position_title) AS 'Required Skills'
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT quali_name) AS 'Required Qualifications'
FROM job_seeker
INNER JOIN job_seeker_profile ON job_seeker.seeker_ID = job_seeker_profile.seeker_ID
INNER JOIN qualifications ON job_seeker_profile.qualification_ID = qualifications.qualification_ID
INNER JOIN skill_types ON job_seeker_profile.skill_type_ID = skill_types.skill_type_ID
INNER JOIN skill_areas ON skill_areas.area_ID = skill_areas.area_ID
INNER JOIN job_pos ON qualifications.qualification_ID = job_pos.qualification_ID
WHERE job_pos.qualification_ID = job_seeker_profile.skill_type_ID
    AND job_pos.qualification_ID = job_seeker_profile.qualification_ID
        AND job_pos.job_position_ID = 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run where clauses like:

```
WHERE (
        SELECT job_pos.qualification_ID
        FROM job_pos
        WHERE job_pos.qualification_ID = job_seeker_profile.skill_type_ID
            AND job_pos.qualification_ID = job_seeker_profile.qualification_ID
        )
    AND job_pos.job_position_ID = 7;
```

You need a condition, so something equals the nested query...... You can't just shove a nested query in the where clause and expect MySQL to magically know what you are trying to do you need to tell MySQL what you want to compare....